# Roman Catholic and being Baptized for a second time in a Coptic church

Tags: catholicism, baptism, coptic

I would like to understand if there are any repercussions of being baptized again in a Coptic church to be married there.  I want to understand what this does to me in standing with my Roman Catholic upbringing and still being a Roman Catholic.

Comment: Is it really necessary? The Catholic Church and the Coptic Orthodox Church [recognise each other's baptism](https://egyptianstreets.com/2017/04/29/pope-francis-and-pope-tawadros-sign-baptism-recognition-agreement-in-cairo/). The answer to your question depends on whether than recognition still stands or not.

Comment: I said the same to my daughter.  the she was told by the coptic priest not sure why they are told she needed to be baptized coptic to get married in the coptic church.  we will see how this plays out.

Comment: Please talk to a Catholic priest about this before you take any action.

Comment: Should the Coptic Church recognize the Catholic baptism, a second baptism in the Coptic Church will not be possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would not get baptized in the Coptic Church under these circumstances. If you know you are validly baptized once, it is sacrilegious to get baptized again. We believe in one baptism, and one baptism alone. You are undermining the efficacy and gravity of baptism and trivializing the sacrament if you receive it multiple times.

It's also not metaphysically possible, so nothing but sacrilege is achieved.